# How to update JTable and JTree when values of variables change?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable, jtree

I am new to Java Swing .

I have a HashMap like this :  HashMap < String,CustomObject > map=new HashMap<>();
String is a name   CustomObject has 3 Integers.

I have created a JTable where there are 5 columns

1. slno         Integer
2. name         String
3. physics     (CustomObject Integer)
4. chemistry   (CustomObject Integer)
5. mathematics (CustomObject Integer)

These Integers are updated at run time by various **Threads** .

Right now I have a REFRESH button which when clicked clears the JTable and populates latest values

How do you make these changing values update JTable .

Which functionality of swing and awt should i use to achieve this ?
I have a similar problem with JTree as well.

Comment: *"Right now I have a REFRESH button which when clicked clears the JTable and populates latest values"*  You might use a Swing based `Timer` to check the map, and if changed (possibly best to keep a `dataHasChanged` attribute), update the table and tree.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That is one of the solution.
is there a way to not poll but automatically update ?

Comment: *"but automatically update"*  I think that is where the answer of MAdProgrammer was leading towards.

Answer (score 2):

The models of of `JTree` and `JTable` are responsible for telling the view that they should be updated.

What you need is some way to know when the data in your `HashMap` and tell the models to update themselves some how.

Something like an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) or [Command/Producer-Consumer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html) can work here.

How you update the models will depend on which implementation of the models you're using, but since you've not provided that information, it's not easy to suggest how you should solve the problem further

Comment: I knew there was a good reason for making my comment a ..comment.  After seeing your (so much more 'OO') answer, you've confirmed my suspicion that it is best *left* as a comment.

Comment: I havent written any custom code for JTable , In netbeans i have used the drag and drop features to insert a jtable When Refresh Button is clicked this piece of code is run `namesJTableModel =(DefaultTableModel) namesJTable.getModel(); namesJTableModel.setRowCount(0); for loop{ //populate jtable namesJTableModel.addRow(new Object[]{i,name,int1,int2,int3}) }`

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` has nice `addRow` and `removeRow` methods...try them.  Just make sure you are modifying the models from within the context of the EDT or it blow up in your face.

Comment: @MadProgrammer what is EDT ?

Comment: you want to use List instead of HashWhatever, especially for JTable

Comment: @harvey123 what is EDT --- search for, .... near station is Oracle tutorial Concurency in Swing

Comment: @mKorbel what are the advantages of making it a list?  does it have functions which are compatible with JTable

Comment: all points from your questions is good described in Orcles tutorials How to use Table and Tree

Comment: @mKorbel I will check it out . Thanks.
please do post links to any other important tutorials

Comment: (what are the advantages of making it a list?) == 1st. real question in this thread, HashXxx haven't indexing, you can't use XxxCellRenderer/XxxCellEditor/RowFilter/RowSorter correctly

Comment: `JTable` is a list of rows (vertically) of column values (horizontally), this lends it self really well to a `List` within a `List`

Comment: @mKorbel Ok , Hash doesnt allow operations like sort which are available in ArrayList , Got It thanks.